# Parsing xml response

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a JAVA application where I am sending some xml requests and receiving xml responses. I first receive response in string and then write a file and storing this file into file system. Then while parsing the xml response file I am accessing this from file system and use some of the data for further business logic.

```
File file = new File("log\\XMLMessage\\LastXMLResponse.xml");

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(file);
```

Now I am thinking to distribute this JAVA application via Java Web Start (JWS) application and as I know I cannot keep this file into jar file since there will be modification in this file on regular basis.

What do you suggest me to do? Can I parse the String directly (no need to store the response into file)?

```
Document doc = db.parse(xmlMessage);
```

or where can I keep this file? I don't want to show this file to the user of my application.

Comment: Why do you receive the responses in a sting and not in a stream, otherwise you could consume it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Take the String, make a StringReader from String, make a InputSource from StringReader, then call parse on your DocumentBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can parse the string directly,no need to store it in a file.

Try this:

```
String xml = "<xml></xml>";
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
System.out.println(doc);
```

Comment: And you can read the String directly, no need to go via bytes ;)

Comment: yes, Thomas has reason, the call to getBytes() in string adds an unnecesary overhead. 
You should do something like: 
    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<xml></xml>")));