# How to convert/parse string into arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm doing a get call and getting the response through InputStreamReader.
So my string looks like this.

"["a", "b", "c"]"

I need to iterate through that string. 
I've tried making into arraylist using List, JSONArray, but cannot seem to loop through.

I rarely work with Java so I'm lost. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below logic will help to loop the string array,

```
String[] input = {"a", "b", "c"};  

          List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(input);  

          for (String str : stringList) {  
             System.out.println(str);  
             // your logic on looped string
          }
```

Comment: Thanks, I replaced [] with "" and split it with , and then created list like your example.

Answer (score 1):

Is that the whole response? Typically, you get a JSON or XML object or something of that sort in the response, and you can use some [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899232/how-to-parse-this-json-response-in-java) [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612911/parsing-xml-response) to parse fields from it for you. See if that is the case.

If not, then it is simply a raw `String`. In that case, you need to use String operations to parse it. Use [String.split(", ")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) which should give you a String array with 3 strings: `["a", "b", "c"]`. you can use [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) on this to get an `ArrayList` from this.

Comment: Thank you, I did use your answer and one below to solve it.